# Mp4 video Within Cargo Collective playing fine on Chrome Browser but not on Safari / mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, video, mp4

New to Stack Overflow, good be connected!

My student portfolio page i've just built on Cargo Collective has an mp4 that loops at the top of the page and i've coded a mute on/off button - all works fine on chrome/macbook but on my iphone, ipad and on safari on desktopp just comes up with a sort of broken video window.

Any tips here? Here's the URL https://jakeebuckley.cargo.site/

Cheers!

Jake

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem and given cargo.site is a proprietary website perhaps in the first instance you can contact their support team? https://support.cargo.site/Contact

Comment: Hey, you mean it's working for you? Unfortunately Cargo can't help - they were my first port of call. Thanks for your response whatever the case :)